# What version of WindowsAzure.Storage is supported by Azure Functions v3?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

I am using Azure Functions V3 with runtime stack of dot net 3.1, and have a business logic of Storage Blob handling using `WindowsAzure.Storage` SDK of version 9.3.3. When I run the function app, I get this error:

> System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.IListBlobItem> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.ListBlobs(System.String, Boolean, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobListingDetails, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobRequestOptions, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.OperationContext)'.'

I would like to know what version of `WindowsAzure.Storage` SDK is compatible with Azure Functions V3. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For .NET applications, the new extension version also changes the types that you can bind to, replacing the types from `WindowsAzure.Storage` and `Microsoft.Azure.Storage` with newer types from [Azure.Storage.Blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs) and also notified in the following [documentation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/).

[image]

This SO Thread helps you from [how to replace `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` with `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64185751/how-to-replace-microsoft-windowsazure-storage-with-microsoft-azure-storage-blob).

If you are working with the `WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue` with .Net 3.1, then please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66857365/is-windowsazure-storage-queue-compatible-with-dotnet-core-3-1).

Comment: Hi Hari Krishna Rajoli, thanks for your answer. My team is currently not in a plan to perform any SdK upgradation. We have some dependencies with `WindowsAzure.Storage`. Is there a way to resolve this error with V3 function with .net core 3.1?

Comment: `WindowsAzure.Storage` is deprecated and the last version 9.3.3 was released in Nov 2018. Though it still works and is not yet out of support, it is recommended to move to the newer `Azure.Storage.Blob`s package to leverage better performance, update, feature release, and continued support in the future. Please Refer for supporting [storage extensions of Azure functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#storage-extension-5x-and-higher)

Comment: I am not asking for support of this deprecated package, but just a way to resolve this error in my question if possible

Comment: Could you please provide the details on which step you're getting this error?

Comment: I have a timer trigger function and I call a method to list all the blobs, As soon as I call my method, I get this error. Any ways, I have fixed this now by upgrading to the latest version SDK `Azure.Storage.Blobs`, but still not sure about the actual reason.